# mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near ',' --COALESCE

Tags: php, coalesce

Hi i have problem witch part of sql query in php.

```
...
$sql.= " --COALESCE(SUM(CASE kontrole.zakres & 4 WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),0) AS ADR,";
$sql.= " COALESCE(SUM(dbo._IS_ADR(kontrole.pojazd_key)),0) AS ADR,";
...
```

Generate error:

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: echo total $sql;
echo $sql;
then run it phpmyadmin

Comment: Can I see your full query ?

Comment: that query working in sql server management studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an additional comma in the second SQL line that breaks the syntax in your query.

```
...
$sql.= " --COALESCE(SUM(CASE kontrole.zakres & 4 WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),0) 
AS ADR,";
$sql.= " COALESCE(SUM(dbo._IS_ADR(kontrole.pojazd_key)),0) AS ADR";
...
```

Comment: Its part of sql query comma at end need to stay/

Comment: Im just telling you what is triggering your error based on the code I can see. I have no more context so i can only answer based on the information provided

Comment: You have right.
Maybe problem is function _IS_ADR ?

Comment: Problem was permissions on execute function _IS_ADR

Answer (score 0):

I think its problem witch permission on the object '_IS_ADR'